How do I set up a virtual Alexa device for testing a skill locally in VS Code?
I am trying to set up Visual Studio Code so that I can test an Alexa Skill in Python. I am following the instructions on this page:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/ask-toolkit/vs-code-testing-simulator.html
To accomplish this, that page says you must create a virtual Alexa device and then register it with VS Code. However, the page that it links to doesn't allow creation of the device and gives an error message, "At this time, you are unable to register new AVS Products"
So, is there some other way to create the virtual Alexa device?
If it matters, I have a free Amazon developer account, and I am the admin.
The problem is in the step, "Register a virtual Alexa device". The instructions say:
"To enable audio output and Alexa Presentation Language (APL) touch events in the simulator, follow the steps to set up a virtual Alexa device, and then register the device with your Amazon account. You must have a registered product before you can create the virtual device. For details, see Register a Product with Alexa Voice Service (AVS)."
In the link to Register a Product, you first create a developer account (done) and then create a product by logging into your dashboard and clicking "MANAGE YOUR PRODUCTS". At the top is a warning message, "Alexa Voice Service (AVS) developer tools are no longer generally available for Alexa Built-in". You then click "ADD NEW PRODUCT". At that point, this message shows: "At this time, you are unable to register new AVS Products" and there is no way to create the device.
I was expecting to have a way to register a device so that I can then follow the instructions in the Visual Studio toolkit.
